# Bootstrap content slides under sidebar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[Image with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLJwo.png)

My page content slides under my sidebar menu when content is longer than the sidebar.

I'm using something like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">  // Sidebar
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="col-md-10">
```

Pull-right makes it weird on smaller screens.

How can I resolve this?

EDIT:

I fixed it like this:

```
col-xs-12 col-md-10 pull-right
```

Hope that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should nest your rows and columns:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="col-md-2">Sidebar</div>

    <!-- Page content -->
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Your page content here -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Damien, I'm using your solution but I had to rename col-10 to col-md-10 for it to work. Using default laravel 5.4 bundled bootstrap.

Comment: You're right, I guess you are using Bootstrap 3. I used Bootstrap 4 notation. I just edited it.